# submit a form using jquery, from another site

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to submit a form using jquery but it gives me error in console.

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://ws1.osfi-bsif.gc.ca" from accessing a frame with origin "http://jsfiddle.net". Protocols, domains, and ports must match
```

here is my code:-

```
post('http://ws1.osfi-bsif.gc.ca/WebApps/FINDAT/DTIBanks.aspx?T=0&LANG=E', {DTIWebPartManager$gwpDTIBankControl1$DTIBankControl1$institutionTypeCriteria$institutionsDropDownList: 'Z005',DTIWebPartManager$gwpDTIBankControl1$DTIBankControl1$dtiReportCriteria$monthlyDropDownList:'DTI-1',DTIWebPartManager$gwpDTIBankControl1$DTIBankControl1$dtiReportCriteria$monthlyDatesDropDownList:'11 - 2014'});


 function post(path, params, method) {
method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

// The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
// It can be made less wordy if you use one.
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", method);
form.setAttribute("action", path);

for(var key in params) {
    if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
     }
}

document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
}
```

here is working JSFiddle:-

```
http://jsfiddle.net/kokmut5v/1/
```

Comment: It's probably because of [Same-origin policy restrictions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Comment: May be you are right, But how we can get results of this form, by any script, from another domain?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is indeed the same-origin policy since the form is loaded from a different domain compare to the domain of the parent window. 
I reckon you should put the form in an iframe and add `sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-forms"` to the iframe.
For more information about iframe and sandbox, you can have a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp) and [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/)